# Parsing values that one under the another with one empty cell in between in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]

I am trying to parse values that are formatted top and bottom to a column which will have their ID and name side by side like shown in the attachment. I have tried couple formulas and data extract model in excel but no luck. Is there away to parse these values like the attachments D,E column using formula,VBA, or text editor?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in D1 and copy over one column and down:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*3+COLUMN(A$1))
```

The `*3` is the pattern (every third row)  While `COLUMN(A$1)` returns `1` or the row in which the data starts.  If it starts in row 2 then one would use `COLUMN(B$1)` instead.

[image]